# Android - Can't make the textview below the framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView and FrameLayout inside a LinearLayout.
I can't make the TextView below the framelayout, it keeps staying at the top.

This is my code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnGoToTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/buttongototop"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnGoToTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/buttongototop"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Pay attention to the `FrameLayout`'s `layout_weight` and `layout_height`. If you kept the height with `match_parent`, it would fit the whole screen, positioning the `TextView` **right after** the end of the screen.

Check this link about [`layout_weight` in `LinearLayout`s](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight).

Answer (score 0):

Try to invert the order of frameLayout and textView considering that you are in a LinearLayout;)

Comment: Hi, I tried but the TextView disappeared. I use getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mf).commit() to display a listView, could it cause this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnGoToTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/buttongototop"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but the TextView disappeared. I use getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mf).commit() to display a listView, could it cause this problem ?

Comment: change to `android:layout_height="wrap_content" ` in frame layout

Answer (score 0):

do the following changes to your `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Let me know if it works.