# Toolbar overlaps content view

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the **"?attr/actionBarSize"** for the TextView to show up below the App Bar. I know that the actionBarSize height is 56dp, but I think the height of the small status bar should be added as well. Is there a property available so that I don't have to do this programmatically but in XML?

**activity_some.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/drawer_layout_include" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**drawer_layout_include:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        layout="@layout/header_tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**header_tool_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

These files are just the plain files from the Android Studio Navigation drawer project.

[image]

Comment: share **`app_bar_main`** layout.xml with question

Comment: Try to put FrameLayout in LinearLayout... https://stackoverflow.com/a/24449345/5281666

Comment: post an screen-shot in android

Comment: drawer_layout_include and header_tool_bar.xml both are same

Comment: done, anybody knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing drawer menu in confusing way. Correct way to implement drawer is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical">
        // your toolbar
        <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar_default" />
// content to show below toolbar, it can be layout or fragments
        <include layout="@layout/activity_main_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

      ....

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is all about drawer layout, why you need to write a complex code.